# file_get_contents failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal > Server Error in

Tags: php, web-scraping

I see many questions matching to my issue. But none of them is providing any workable solution. so instead of making complex functionality i need simple solution. Please I dont' want cURL. I've already done a lot with this code.

I'm working on a scraping project and need to load the contents of product revisions from ebay.

I am using PHP function

```
file_get_contents();
```

Here is the URL i'm troubling with.

```
https://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemRevisionDetails&item=272908801183
```

this file_get_contents(); is working perfectly fine on different URLs but don't know why not on this.

This is the code i'm using.

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('https://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemRevisionDetails&item=272908801183');
echo $html;
?>
```

but i'm getting this error..

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(https://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemRevisionDetails&&item=272908801183):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal
>   Server Error in
>   /Users/samz/Documents/projects/scraping/test.php
>   on line 3

Comment: please include more of test.php. What is on and around line 3?

Comment: on line 3 is ... echo $html; the script i wrote above. you can copy and paste this script in any php file and hit hinter. You will get the same error. this was the simplest method to re-create error for you gurus. BTW it should be line 2. I've an extra line on my test.php file

Comment: why are you not using the ebay API ?

Comment: I didn't know that.. @nogad  .. thanks for this tip.. I will check out that a well.. but it was doing through multiple site...

Comment: @nogad I've tested their basic tutorial on http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/HowTo/GettingStarted_PHP_NV_XML/GettingStarted_PHP_NV_XML.html and i'm getting the same error "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error in...."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) (read the tip on blue rectangle) can be easily blocked on server side through [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)  avoid using it. When you want to get data from an other site use curl instead. http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php, there are plenty of options that you can use with curl, by playing a bit the following code can work with your url.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemRevisionDetails&item=272908801183");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

and by echoing the $data varible you can see the whole page.

```
echo $data;
```

you can try parsing the data from the page by utilizing php [DOM Methods](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and convert them to the data type you want (object class, array etc).

Answer (score 1):

This is file_get_contents (read the tip on blue rectangle) can be easily blocked on server side through php.ini avoid using it. When you want to get data from an other site use curl instead. http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php, there are plenty of options that you can use with curl, by playing a bit the following code can work with your url.

Comment: Thanks @STEVEN. Yes it worked back in 2017 using curl :)

Comment: This is shortened duplicate of accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47296900/7264739 What's the point?