# PHP file_get_content() fails but wget works?

Tags: php

I am using `file_get_contents()` in PHP:

```
<?php

try {
    file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json/2.217.37.1');
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

but it results in an error message:

```
file_get_contents(http://ip-api.com/json/2.217.37.1): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
```

but when I use `wget` it works:

```
$ wget http://ip-api.com/json/2.217.37.1
$ cat 2.217.37.1
{"status":"success","country":"United Kingdom","countryCode":"GB","region":"ENG","regionName":"England","city":"Reading","zip":"RG1","lat":51.4566,"lon":-0.968,"timezone":"Europe/London","isp":"Sky Broadband","org":"Sky UK Limited","as":"AS5607 Sky UK Limited","query":"2.217.37.1"}
```

What is causing this behaviour in PHP?

The error message is not helpful.

Comment: Are you running `wget` on the same server as PHP?

Comment: @Barmar Yes I am.

Comment: The PHP script works fine for me.

Comment: Do you have `allow_url_fopen` enabled in your `php.ini`?

Comment: Can you get it using `curl` in PHP?

Comment: Check if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295100/file-get-contents-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed-http-1-1-500-inter solves your problem.

Comment: @Barmar It has also worked for me. PHP seems to work intermediately where as `wget` constantly works. Even right now, PHP is giving me the error message but `wget` works immediately after.

Comment: You mean intermittently?

Comment: Are you doing it in a loop in the PHP script? There might be a rate limiter.

Comment: `curl()` seems to constantly work like `wget`.

Comment: Can you `file_get_contents()` any other url, or are you getting the same error then? Like `file_get_contents('https://duckduckgo.com');`?